# How to change quartz job scheduled time manually using sql?

Tags: java, sql-server, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling, quartz

I am using Quartz job scheduler for running some jobs. Using java api I am managing the job.

When I reschedule a job to different time using java,

```
   scheduler.deleteJob(jobName, jobGroupName);

   addJobsInScheduler(jobName, jobGroupName, triggerName,
                           triggerGroup, newTime, schoolName);
```

The job is getting rescheduled and triggered at the specified time.

Now have a requirement in which I have to reschedule the job without UI(without Java api).

From my understanding when I reschedule a job the following table entries getting updated.

> QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS
>
> QRTZ_TRIGGERS
>
> QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS

So I manually updated the fire time in QRTZ_TRIGGERS,QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS. But the job is not triggered at the updated time.

Is that possible to achieve my requirement?

Note: I am using sql server 2008 for my backend.

[image: Table Structure:]

Comment: Is there a way to take a screenshot of the tables you mentioned? I would like to see a sample data if this is the same as what we used. I might be able to help you. :)

Comment: @dco thanks for your help. From hiroyukik's  comments it's clear that we cannot update quartz internal table. So i ll find other way to figure it out. Also as per my company policy I should not share my table data outside.

Comment: actually you can. We updated the quartz table timing using T-SQL. mask the data and leave the schedule. Or create a dummy table so we could see definition and sample data.

Comment: @dco can u see the question description. I have updated it to have table structures. Would that be helpful?

Comment: yes. You mentioned that you manually updated the table and it did not work. How did you update the table? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: @dco I have deployed Quartz in my JBoss server.  I ran the following queries to manually update it.
**
UPDATE dbo.QRTZ_TRIGGERS SET NEXT_FIRE_TIME = '1489729200794',  PREV_FIRE_TIME = '-1', TRIGGER_STATE = 'WAITING';

update QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS set CRON_EXPRESSION='00 10 11 ? * *

Answer (score 4):

I believe you shouldn't update the Quartz tables directly with SQL. There are no right way with SQL in Quartz documents so that, no one guarantee not to have any changes for the interface between Quartz and database in the future.

According to the documents [Lesson 9: Job Stores](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09)

> Never use a JobStore instance directly in your code. For some reason
>   many people attempt to do this. The JobStore is for behind-the-scenes
>   use of Quartz itself. You have to tell Quartz (through configuration)
>   which JobStore to use, but then you should only work with the
>   Scheduler interface in your code.

You should follow the below document for updating your triggers.

[How-To: Updating a trigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/cookbook/UpdateTrigger.html)

If you have no UI, You need to create new interface for updating your schedules somehow.

Answer (score 3):

From experienced, we just update the NEXT_FIRE_TIME column like this:

```
`UPDATE dbo.QRTZ_TRIGGERS SET NEXT_FIRE_TIME =1491004800 `
```

where 1491004800 is 1st of April 2017 00:00:00 GMT

Use the T-SQL below to get the NEXT_FIRE_TIME you desire. You may need to change the GETUTCDATE().

`SELECT DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', GETUTCDATE())`

Then update the QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS table

`UPDATE dbo.QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS set CRON_EXPRESSION='00 10 11 ? * *'`

where '00 10 11 ? * *' is run 11:10AM daily. You can get the cron expression from [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

This may not be the best practice but from experience it works for us without issues. **I would highly recommend to TEST it first in your lower environment.** Wait for the job to trigger and see if you see any changes on the QRTZ_TRIGGERS table.